# Segfault when using GetElementPtrInst with an ArrayRef containing more than one Value

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm trying to write a toy compiler with LLVM and C++. But whenever I try to create a GetElementPtrInst with more than one Index there is a Segfault.
The documentation about this instruction didn't help me ([API-Documentation](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GetElementPtrInst.html#a3e10b4db1ded36654416d3aed2bc56ba) [Language-Documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#i_getelementptr))

My llvm version is 3.1 and this is on Arch Linux. Just tested it on another Arch machine and got the same error.

Am I doing something wrong?

Here is small working program to illustrate my problem. It can be compiled with:

```
g++ -o segfault_example segfault_example.cpp -Wall -Wextra -pedantic \
    `llvm-config --libs core jit native --cxxflags --ldflags`
```

```cpp
#include <llvm/Module.h>
#include <llvm/Constants.h>
#include <llvm/DerivedTypes.h>
#include <llvm/LLVMContext.h>
#include <llvm/Instructions.h>
#include <llvm/Analysis/Verifier.h>
#include <llvm/ADT/ArrayRef.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

static llvm::LLVMContext& global = llvm::getGlobalContext();
static llvm::Type* int32ty = llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(global);

llvm::ConstantInt* getInt32(int n)
{
    return llvm::ConstantInt::get(llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(global), n);
}

int main()
{
    //setup everything for a minimal example
    llvm::Module* mainModule = new llvm::Module("main", global);

    llvm::FunctionType* ftype = llvm::FunctionType::get(int32ty, false);

    llvm::Function* mainFunction = llvm::Function::Create(
        ftype, llvm::GlobalValue::InternalLinkage, "main", mainModule);

    llvm::BasicBlock* bblock = llvm::BasicBlock::Create(
        global, "entry", mainFunction, 0);

    llvm::AllocaInst* mem = new llvm::AllocaInst(llvm::Type::getInt32PtrTy(global, 0x1000)
        , getInt32(0x1000), 0x1000, "mem", bblock);

    //tests
    //this works
    std::cout << "Testing with one element vector" << std::endl;
    std::vector<llvm::Value*> vect_1;
    vect_1.push_back(getInt32(0));
    llvm::GetElementPtrInst* gep1 =
        llvm::GetElementPtrInst::CreateInBounds(mem, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Value*>(vect_1)
        , "retval", bblock);
    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;

    //this works too, but I can't find this signature in the documentation
    std::cout << "Testing with Value* instead of ArrayRef" << std::endl;
        llvm::GetElementPtrInst::CreateInBounds(mem, getInt32(0), "retval", bblock);
    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;

    //this segfaults
    std::cout << "Filling two element vector" << std::endl;
    std::vector<llvm::Value*> vect_2;
    vect_2.push_back(getInt32(0));
    vect_2.push_back(getInt32(1));
    std::cout << "Testing with two element vector" << std::endl;
    //segfault
    llvm::GetElementPtrInst* gep2 =
        llvm::GetElementPtrInst::CreateInBounds(mem, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Value*>(vect_2)
        , "retval", bblock);
    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;

    mainModule->dump();
    llvm::verifyFunction(*mainFunction);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Found the error. I will try to explain the cause and my solution, but the explanation may be wrong.

The type of `mem` was wrong. (In my case) it needed to be declared using `new llvm::AllocaInst(llvm::ArrayType::get(int32ty, 100), "mem", bblock);`. Creating two levels of indirection ([explanation why there are two indirections](http://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html#why-is-the-extra-0-index-required)). The previous type had only one indirection and dereferencing it with `GetElementPtrInst` and a two element vector therefore didn't work.

I noticed this, when playing with [llvm in the browser](http://llvm.org/demo/) and emiting LLVM C++ Api code.

You can create the C++ Api code for a C example file on the command line like so:

```
clang -c -emit-llvm -o ex.bf example.c
llc -march=cpp -o ex.cpp ex.bf
```

Comment: Both the question and your answer are incredibly helpful -- thank you! PS: you should accept your answer.